# Where and how to store python script that gets executed with Jar?

Tags: java

I have a Java program that calls a Python program using the code below

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "python3", "myprogram.py", deviceSerial });
```

I want to have the python script also ship with the executable jar. Do I put the Python script in the resources folder? if so how would I call it?

Answer (score 2):

You could load the classpath resource into an InputStream and write that to the disk during runtime.

After that you could execute the newly created file.

EDIT: Comment from @ygor: `System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")` is a good location for the output file.

Comment: System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") is a good place to write the script to